# Where Do I Find The Astra Default Font Family That All Text Elements Are Inheriting From?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm working with the Astra theme and I'm looking at my Typography settings in the Customizer. All of the elements (body, H1, H2, etc) have the Font Family set to Inherit. Where do I find the actual font family that these are all inheriting from, in case I want to change this? LMK if you need more information.

Comment: In your browser inspector's Style panel in the Elements tab, you should be able to see all rules which are applied to a particular element. Select some text, then locate the font-family rule which is not `inherit` or crossed out. The CSS file responsible for the rule should be listed above that entry

Comment: This question should be asked of the theme's support channels. Third-party theme support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Astra uses 'system fonts'. To change the defaults, look in Appearance / Customize / Global.

https://wpastra.com/docs/font-selection/

Best of luck!